# characterisation of direct sum of abelian groups

Tags: abelian-groups, direct-sum

The direct sum of abelian groups can be defined in several equivalent ways, but I have some problem proving the equivalence.

Definition 1:
Given abelian groups $A$ and $B$, the direct sum is defined as the castesian product $A \times B$, equipped with the operation $(a,b)(a',b') = (aa',bb')$. Then $A$ can be identified as the subgroup $A \times \lbrace e_B \rbrace$ in $A \times B$. The case for $B$ similar.

Definition 2:
Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of an abelian group $G$. $G$ is said to be the direct product of $A$ and $B$ iff every element $g \in G$  can be expressed uniquely as $g = a + b$, with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

However, I have difficulty proving the following: i.e. if [EDIT: additional assumption: A and B are subgroups of an abelian group G and] $G \cong A \times B$  as defined in definition 1, then every element $g \in G$ can be expressed uniquely as $g = a + b$, with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Given only an isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \rightarrow G$, I can only conclude that $g = \phi(a,e_B) + \phi(e_A,b)$, but I do not know whether $\phi(a,e_B) = a$ and $\phi(e_A,b) = b$. I know they almost look the same, and should not matter much in the spirit of 'up to isomorphism', but I still cannot see how I can proceed to show $g = a + b$.

Can anyone help me proceed? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've passed over this question already 4 times and I still cannot understand it, or better: I can't see where **exactly** is the problem. Perhaps you should separate the very, very point that is giving you problems. This is a question about a rather basic point in an elementary course at undergraduate level. Seeing that nobody (but me right now) has posted anything one hour after you post your questions makes me wonder whether others don't understand completely what's going on here, too.

Comment: The problem is that I want to prove that: G≅A×B implies every element in G can be expressed uniquely as a sum a + b. I can conclude g=ϕ(a,e_B)+ϕ(e_A,b), but not g = a + b. I simplified the question. Does that help? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, that! Well, if $\;a+b=a'+b'\;$ , then $\;a-a'=b-b'\in A\cap B=\{0\}\implies a=a'\,,\,\,b=b'\;$ and we're done.

Comment: I know this sounds like a stupid question, but would you mind explaining how we can assert that $A \cap B = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ from that assumption that there is an isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \rightarrow G$? Because we do not know whether $\phi (A \times \lbrace e_B \rbrace) = A$.

Comment: Read your last comment before mine: you said that you want to prove that $\;G\cong A\times B\implies \;\exists!\;\text{expression}\;\;g=a+b\;\;\forall\,g\in G\;$ , and this follows from the basic **condition** that the intersection $\;A\cap B\;$ **must** be trivial for a direct product to exist.

Comment: I should have worded more carefully. I meant G≅A×B according to definition 1, i.e. there exists an isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \rightarrow G$, where $A \times B$ is the cartesian product. Then we do have $(A \times {\lbrace e_B \rbrace}) \cap ({\lbrace e_A \rbrace} \times B) = {\lbrace e \rbrace} $ in the cartesian product $A \times B$, but we cannot ensure that $A \times {\lbrace e_B \rbrace}$ is mapped by the the isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \rightarrow G$ to $A$ itself, so we do not know how A and B, as subgroups of the abstract group G, intersect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25773/discussion-between-alex-and-timbuc).

Comment: Read my answer below (too long for a comment). Observe then that as you put it, we can *not* state that $\;A,B\subset G\;$ so we can't be sure that $\;ab\in G\;$ at all, but we **have** isomorphic copies of $\;A,B\;$ in $\;G\;$ .

Answer (score -1):

Related to last comment:

But then there is no much problem imo, either: in the *cartesian* product every pair $\;(a,b)\;$ is **unique**, meaning: $\;(a,b)=(a',b')\iff a=a'\,,\,\,b=b'\;$ , so if $\;\phi:A\times B\to G\;$ is a **group** isomorphism, then if $\;\phi(a,1_B)=g_A\;,\;\;\phi(1_A,b)=g_B\;$ , we have then $\;g=g_Ag_B\in G\;$, and this expression is unique, no matter where $\;A\times 1_B\,,\,\,1_A\times B\;$ are mapped to by $\;\phi\;$ .

Also, observe that $\;A\times1_B\cong A\;,\;\;1_A\times B\cong B\;$ and this is as much as we can say in this respect.

Comment: I am sorry for this serious omission: what if A and B are subgroups of G? So, A and B are subgroups of an abelian group G and there is an isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \rightarrow G$, where A x B is the cartesian product. In this case, it makes sense to ask whether g = a + b, where $a \in A$ and $ b \in B$, and $\phi (a,e_B)$ may not be a.